# How to send mails with given bcc field with swaks?

Tags: email, sendmail

How do I send a mail thanks to `swaks` with BCC recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it easy:

```
swaks --to email1,email3 --from email2 --server smtp --auth LOGIN --auth-user "" --auth-password "" --header "Subject: test" --data "Subject: test

To: email1
Bcc: email3
From: email2
MIME-VERSION: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"123456789\"

--123456789
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

    <html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Swaks FAQ](http://jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/faq.html):

> ... to send a message to aa@example.com and bb@example.com, but only include aa@example.com in the To: header (or, put another way, to BCC bb@example.com), the following would work:

> `swaks --to aa@example.com,bb@example.com --header "To: aa@example.com"`